# How do I disconnect this plug?

Tags: door, peugeot, central-locking, connector

This plug is inside the door of my 2001 Peugeot 306. I’ve tried everything to remove it. It’s the plug that connects to the locking system for central locking and such. I can’t find any documentation or other explanation on how to disconnect it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The white tab (purple arrow) needs to be pushed back beyond the brown latch (blue arrow). Put something between the two like a very tiny screwdriver or an awl (or some kind of pointy probe).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like poking something in that little hole and pulling it to the left should release the latch, then pull on the connector and wires if necessary.
[image]